# C# EF 6 CurrentValues.SetValues cannot change Object's Key Information

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I have seen other questions about this same error, but I am unable to correct the error with those suggestions in my code; I think that this is a different problem and not a duplicate.

I have an app that makes a series of rules, of which the user can set properties in the GUI. There is a table of Rules in a connected database, with the primary key on the Rule.Id. When the user saves changes to a rule, the existing rule gets "IsActive=0" to hide it, then a new database record is made with the properties from the GUI written to the database. It looks to the user as though they have edited the rule, but the database actually sees a new rule reflecting the new properties (this allows for a history to be kept), connected to the old rule by another reference field.

In the C# code for the app, the View Model for each rule contains an EF Rule object property. When the user clicks "save" I use the parameters set in the view to build the `ruleViewModel.Rule` for each ruleViewModel they want to save, with porperties matching the GUI. The MainViewModel contains the DbContext object called `dbo`, so I use the `ruleViewModel.Rule` to write to the `mainViewModel.dbo.Entry` which I save to the Entity Framework. Here are the three basic steps performed for each saveable Rule View Model:

```
// get the rule from the GUI and use it to make sure we are updating the right rule in EF (which is connected to the mainViewModel)
var dboItem = ruleViewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.Rules.Single(r => r.Id == ruleViewModel.Rule.Id);

// set the values in the EF item to be those we got from the GUI
ruleViewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.Entry(dboItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(ruleViewModel.Rule);

// Save the differences
ruleViewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.SaveChanges();
```

If the user only saves a single rule, it all works fine, but if they subsequently try to save another, or if they save more than one at once, they get the following error, which is return by the `..SetValues(..)` line:

```
Message = "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "
```

I see from other questions on this subject that there is a feature of EF that stops you from writing the same object twice to the database with a different Id, so this error often happens within a loop. I have tried using some of the suggestions, like adding

```
viewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.Rules.Add(dboItem);
```

and

```
viewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.Entry(dboItem).Property(x => x.Id).IsModified = false;
```

before the `SaveChanges()` command, but that has not helped with the problem (not to mention changing the function of the code). I see that some other suggestions say that the Entry should be created within the loop, but in this case, the entries are all existing rules in the database - it seems to me (perhaps erroneously) that I cannot create them inside the save loop, since they are the objects over which the loop is built - for each entity I find, I want to save changes.

I'm really confused about what to do and tying myself increasingly in knots trying to fix the error. It's been several days now and my sanity and self-esteem is beginning to wane! Any pointers to get me working in the right direction to stop the error appearing and allow me to set the database values would be really welcome as I feel like I have hit a complete dead end! The first time around the loop, everything works perfectly.

Comment: You better show in code what actually happens. It's impossible to piece it together *exactly* from a description. Esp. the life cycle of the context and what happens with keys and history records.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the questionable location of the DbContext and view models containing entities, this looks like it would work as expected. I'm assuming from the MVVM tag that this is a Windows application rather than a web app. The only issue is that this assumes that the Rule entity in your ruleViewModel is detached from the DbContext. If the DbContext is still tracking that entity reference then getting the entity from the DbContext again would pass you back the same reference.

It would probably be worth testing this once in a debug session. If you add the following:

```
var dboItem = ruleViewModel.MainViewModel.dbo.Rules.Single(r => r.Id == ruleViewModel.Rule.Id);
bool isReferenceSame = Object.ReferenceEquals(dboItem, ruleViewModel.Rule);
```

Do you get an isReferenceSame value of True or False? If True, the DbContext in your main view model is still tracking the Rule entity and the whole get dboItem and SetValues isn't necessary. If False, then the ruleViewModel is detached.

If the entities are attached and being tracked then edits to the view model entities would be persisted when you call a SaveChanges on the DbContext. (No load & SetValues needed) This should apply to single or multiple entity edits.

If the entities are detached then normally the approach for updating an entity across DbContext instances would look more like:

```
var context = mainViewModel.dbo; 

foreach( var ruleViewModel in updatedRuleViewModels)
{
    // This should associate the Entity in the ruleViewModel with the DbContext and set it's tracking state to Modified.
    context.Entry(ruleViewModel.Rule).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

There are a couple of potential issues with this approach that you should consider avoiding if possible. A DbContext should be kept relatively short lived, so seeing a reference to a DbContext within a ViewModel is a bit of a red flag. Overall I don't recommend putting entity references inside view models or passing them around outside of the scope of the DbContext they were created in. EF certainly supports it, but it requires a bit more care and attention to assess whether entities are tracked or not, and in situations like web applications, opens the domain to invalid tampering. (Trusting the entity coming in where any change is attached or copied across overwriting the data state)

Comment: Yes, `isReferenceSame` returns true each time it goes around the loop. It seems from what you are saying that with my limited understanding of EF (this is my first time using it), I will probably need to restructure a lot of the app to avoid this problem. I say that because I guess the best way to fix the issue is to standardise the structure. Would you agree with that? It's going to be a lot of work, I suspect! Do you know a good place to look at how I should be doing it?

Comment: If the references are the same then it sounds like you are dealing with a long-lived DbContext. What happensif you remove the reload dboItem, remove the copy/setting state, and just call SaveChanges() on the MainViewModel DbContext? (dbo) If this is a long-lived context and those entity references are tracked, then SaveChanges would persist them. Long-lived contexts have several drawbacks to consider such as ever-growing memory use, longer operations due to growing # of tracked entities, plus stale data and extra effort to discard "bad" changes that contaminate a save.

Comment: I have found a course that I will go through & learn how to avoid the long-lived Dbcontext -you are right that it is causing problems & your answer has opened my eyes a bit! I think the issues are larger than can be addressed here.

Comment: I will answer this question when l have worked out The way, but you have shown me the problem, so thanks for that